# Write a unicode character to a file in a binary way

Tags: python, unicode

I have the following code to write an ASCII "@" character to a file in a binary fashion:

```
fin=open('a.bin','wb')
fin.write('\x40')
fin.close()
```

It turns out the a "@" character has been written to "a.bin", which has a length of 1-byte.

However, when I tried to write a unicode character instead:

```
fin=open('a.bin','wb')
fin.write(u'\x40')
fin.close()
```

It turned out that "a.bin" is still 1-byte long. I thought it should be 2-byte long since a unicode character takes 2-bytes. There may be some trivial thing that I overlooked.

Comment: Unicode characters are **not** the same thing as encoded bytes.

Comment: Also look at the documentation for the `io` module.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are confusing Unicode with encodings. An encoding is a standard that represents text as within the confines of individual values in the range of 0-255 (bytes), while Unicode is a standard that describes codepoints representing textual glyphs. The two are related but *not the same thing*.

The Unicode standard includes several encodings. UTF-16 is *one* such encoding that uses 2 bytes per codepoint, but it is not the only encoding included in the standard. UTF-8 is another such encoding, and it uses a *variable* number of bytes per codepoint.

Your file, however, is written using ASCII, the default codec used by Python 2 when you do not specify an explicit encoding. If you expected to see *2* bytes per codepoint, encode to UTF-16 explicitly:

```
fin.write(u'\x40'.encode('utf16-le')
```

This writes UTF-16 in *little endian* byte order; there is also a `utf16-be` codec. Normally, for multi-byte encodings like UTF-16 or UTF32, you'd also include a BOM, or Byte Order Mark; it is included automatically when you write UTF-16 without picking any endianes.

```
fin.write(u'\x40'.encode('utf16')
```

I **strongly** urge you to study up on Unicode, codecs and Python before you continue:

- [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) by Joel Spolsky
- The [Python Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html)
- [Pragmatic Unicode](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html) by Ned Batchelder

Answer (score 1):

- Character numbers from U+0000 to U+007F (US-ASCII repertoire)
  correspond to octets 00 to 7F (7 bit US-ASCII values).  A direct
  consequence is that a plain ASCII string is also a valid UTF-8
  string.
- [UTF-8, a transformation format of ISO 10646](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3629)

Comment: Python is encoding to **ASCII** here, if the OP had used a codepoint anywhere beyond U+007F he'd have encountered a `UnicodeEncodeError`.

Comment: You are writing *bytes* already encoded then. That is *not* a unicode value. Your terminal encoded the `й` codepoint, or your editor saved bytes to a source file, fully encoded.

Comment: Just because your terminal or editor displays those bytes again, decoded, doesn't mean you are not dealing with bytes here. Make it a unicode literal with `u''` and try again, on Python 2.

Answer (score 1):

Martijn is right in his elaborate answer:  Learn more about Unicode first.  But a smaller answer than reading large educational documents can be this:

When writing a Python unicode value (`u'\x40'` in your case) to a stream (an open file in your case), this abstract unicode value must be converted into a concrete stream of bytes.  For this *encodings* are used.

You can do this explicitly (by using `u'\x40'.encode('foo')`) or you do it implicitly; then some encoding is being used.  In your case either `"ascii"` or `"utf8"` which both represent a unicode-@ as a single byte with value 40.

What you seem to *want* is using an encoding in which the unicode-@ is represented as a two-byte value; that would be the encoding `utf-16` for instance.